# Should I give it a Default Value or make it Nullable ?

Tags: mysql, database-migration

I got an error message say

[image]

I suddenly realized that I forgot to `set` the `default value` to one of my field call `note`.

There are 2 ways that I'm thinking on how fix this :

1. Give it a `default value`
2. Make it `nullable`

Since I am very new to the database world, here is my question :

- Either way, I chose to do, does it matter ? Will it effect the performance of any kind ?
- Is there any different them ?

Comment: Performance won't matter between them. Depends on your need. If you want your application to throw an error (which you could catch and handle) if it was null, leave it as is. If the column _should_ have some default value, set a default.  Otherwise, make it nullable.

Comment: The difference is simple: the value. `""` and `NIL` and `0` are technically different values. No idea about performance.

Comment: `NULL` *is* a default value.  It is the default default value if you don't specify anything else (or prevent it using `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll toss my thoughts into this question. For something like a notes section, it might be ok to set the default value to `"None"` (forexample) instead of `NULL`. While it won't make much of a difference performance wise, it would make a difference display wise. Depending on how you show this data to a user, do you want your notes section to have nothing in it at all, or do you want it to say "None Provided" or show nothing at all? For this case, it's a matter of personal preference.

The only thing I would suggest is to be consistent in your conventions. If you have a notes column on another table that has a default value, and this one doesn't, then it's inconsistent and, while likely not harmful, may lead to some frustration/confusion down the road.

Last thing, functionality wise, make sure you're checking for the right things. If you make it `->nullable()` and don't want to show `NULL` results, use `WHERE table.note IS NOT NULL`. If you provide a default value of say `"None"` and don't want to show those, then the `WHERE` would be `WHERE table.note != "None"`.

Hope that provides some insight!

Answer (score 1):

> •Is there any different them ?

It's a big difference between non NULL and NULL in SQL. No performance benefits but there is a lot function which can works with NULL values: ex. `IFNULL()`, `NULLIF()` . With some other functions the behavior may be unexceptable in some cases.

> Either way, I chose to do, does it matter ? Will it effect the
>   performance of any kind ?

No, it won't. Choose what you need/want. Specifally in your case you should give to column a default value. You can make it such way:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER columnName SET DEFAULT 'your value';
```

***! If your table already have a data, you need to make a copy before you start changing its structure***

Answer (score 0):

No change on performance.

It only depends on your needs.

Defaut value = the value you want to set if the user forgets to fill the field. 
For instance "English" would suits as a default language, because many users *would* have chosen this language.
"Mike" will not suit as a default first name, because "Mike" is not the default first name for everyone.

NULL and NOT NULL = if you do not want an information to stay empty.
For instance "Mobile phone" can stay blank, because you don't need that info.
"e-mail address" cannot stay blank, because you will need it later to send e-mails to that person.